# Https connection, resonsecode 500

Tags: android, http, https

I`m trying to get some data through a Https connection using trustAllCertificates.

My intention is to first grab the "Set-Cookie" values (below 4) with a GET request on the loginsite, after that I use them to perform the real POST to this same loginsite but after the requests finish I always get a 500 responsecode. The correct reponse should be 302 giving me the .ASPXAUTH cookie through which I know I am correctly logged in (Although I don`t know this assumption is correct?).

If someone could point in the right direction or help me out, that would be great, banging my head for some time now on this.

```
 GetCookies: ASP.NET_SessionId=xjfnvccto5ttvwlhnfoypg5j
 GetCookies: _culture_sc=nl
 GetCookies: __RequestVerificationToken=tT8uFrYYGeFh8gk57wrc0WRsEFaodG4T5imvoohJC5_wFrkkUt_tyGpWniXHhawFnyCVmxqm5F8XKL0EZFDjVsL89tsuDXBD3GiGpA8yKLY1
 GetCookies: AWSELB="8531CF6912558C4E64C6A46FDD46D2677B2558E852A91BEA8383D429952CE6042E8FD08CBE9912A67B0A1ACDCB474BBF0863366F22F2E637C7C9DF353DCC76C43A6CC30545";$Path="/";$Domain="mobiel.host.nl"
```

Comment: `a 500 responsecode`. And that means?

Comment: @greenapps, 500 means: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
My code is incorrect? I assume yes.

Comment: You have to check server logs to see what is wrong.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, unfortunately I don`t have access to the server.

Comment: @Rad Lexus, done.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I got it working now, in fact I was fetching the token incorrectly, I needed to get it from the loginsite itself and not the value from the Set-Cookie header. As a result the server received incorrect data and gave a 500 responsecode.
I posted the *working code* if someone runs into the same problem.

I wrapped this all up in a *HttpUtility class* using a **static HttpsURLConnection.**

> ```
> /**
>  * Represents an HTTP connection
>  */
> private static HttpsURLConnection httpConn;
> ```

Get the token from Loginsite:

> ```
> private String getToken() {
>     String result = "";
>     try {
>         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mobiel.host.nl/login").get();
>         Element inputElements = doc.getElementsByTag("input").first();
>         result = inputElements.attr("value");
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Handle the cookies:

```
final public void saveCookies(HttpURLConnection connection, Context context) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(myCookies);
    Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();

    List<String> cookiesHeader = null;
    try {
        cookiesHeader = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (cookiesHeader != null && myCookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
            try {
                cookie = cookie.replace("\"", "");
                myCookies.getCookieStore().add(connection.getURL().toURI(), HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                new_cookie = TextUtils.join(";", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies());

                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.myContext).edit().putString("cookie", new_cookie).commit();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

final public void loadCookies(HttpURLConnection connection, Context context) {
    if (myCookies != null && myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join(";", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
        Log.w("NewCookies: ", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies().toString());
    } else {
        new_cookie = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.myContext).getString("cookie" , "");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", new_cookie);
    }
}
```

Disables the SSL certificate checking, use this ONLY for testing purposes:

> ```
> private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
>     TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
>         public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
>             return null;
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
>             // Not implemented
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
>             // Not implemented
>         }
>     } };
>     try {
>         SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
>         sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
>         HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
>     } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

GET Request:

> ```
> public void sendGetRequest(String requestURL, Context context) {
>     try {
>         URL url = new URL(requestURL);
>         disableSSLCertificateChecking(); // Call this only once
>         httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>         httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
>         loadCookies(httpConn, context);
>         httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
>         httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
>         httpConn.setDoInput(true);
>         httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
>         int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
>         if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
>             InputStream in = httpConn.getInputStream();
>             if (httpConn.getContentEncoding() != null && httpConn.getContentEncoding().contains("gzip")) {
>                 GZIPInputStream inn = new GZIPInputStream(in);
>                 saveCookies(httpConn, context); // Save SET-Cookies
>             } else {
>                 saveCookies(httpConn, context); //--//
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

POST Request:

> ```
> public HttpsURLConnection sendPostRequest(String requestURL, Context context) throws IOException {
>     int TIMEOUT_VALUE = 10000;
>     token = getToken(); // Get token from Loginsite
>     Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
>             .appendQueryParameter("__RequestVerificationToken", token)
>             .appendQueryParameter("ReturnUrl", "")
>             .appendQueryParameter("Username", user)
>             .appendQueryParameter("Password", pass);
>     String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
>     try {
>         boolean redirect = false;
>         URL url = new URL(requestURL);
>         HttpsURLConnection httpConn = null;
>         httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>         httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>         httpConn.setDoInput(true);
>         httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
>         httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
>         httpConn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
>         httpConn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
>         httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
>           System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);       
>         httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
>         httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
>         httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(query.length()));
>         // sends POST data
>         OutputStream os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
>         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
>                 new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
>         writer.write(query);
>         writer.flush();
>         writer.close();
>         os.close();
>         // Handle servererror code
>         int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
>         if (status > 400) {
>             InputStream errorstream = httpConn.getErrorStream();
>             BufferedReader br = null;
>             if (errorstream == null) {
>               InputStream inputstream = httpConn.getInputStream();
>                 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
>             } else {
>                 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorstream));
>             }
>             String response = "";
>             String message;
>             while ((nachricht = br.readLine()) != null) {
>                 response += message;
>             }
>         }
>         // Handle redirects, normally, 3xx is redirect
>         if (status != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
>             if (status == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
>                     || status == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
>                     || status == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
>                 redirect = true;
>         }
>         if (redirect) {
>             // get redirect url from "location" header field
>             String newUrl = httpConn.getHeaderField("Location");
>             // Get the cookie if needed, for login
>             saveCookies(httpConn, context);
>             // Open the new connnection again
>             httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>             loadCookies(httpConn, context); //Include the cookies
>             httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
>             httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
>             Log.w("Redirected to URL : ", newUrl);
>         }
>     } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
>         Log.e("More than ", TIMEOUT_VALUE + " elapsed.");
>     }
>     // Check if correctly logged in
>     httpConn.getHeaderFields().toString();
>     List<HttpCookie> cookies = myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies();
>     for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
>         if (cookie.getName().equals(".ASPXAUTH")) {
>             Log.e(".ASPXAUTH-Session: ", "Logged in!");
>         }
>     }
>     saveCookies(httpConn, context); // Save Set-Cookies for next session
>     return httpConn;
> }
> ```

Comment: (Thanks! Don't forget you can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) as well, which will mark the question as 'has an answer that worked'.)

Comment: Thank you, I will accept it as soon as 48 hours have been past.